# How to use exponential back-off logic in Azure device client?

Tags: c#, azure-iot-hub, retry-logic, retrypolicy

I have a job in `c#` which runs every 5 minutes and acts like a heartbeat to check the client status

[image]

When the status is `Disconnected_Retrying`, I exit the timer job assuming built in `retry` logic will work. However, status always comes as `Disconnected_Retrying` and leads to unnecessary calls/request to server every 5 minute. Hence I am thinking of implementing `exponential backoff` method to overcome this issue

Started reading below GitHib code  https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/blob/main/iothub/device/src/RetryPolicies/ExponentialBackoff.cs

But I am not able to understand how to implement it.

Comment: It's unclear to me where the 'client' runs. Is it in your timer function? Is it an IoT device?

Comment: Retry on the function is in case of exception. Do you throw an exception when status is Disconnected_Retrying? Do you not want the function to trigger again in 5 min in case of Disconnected_Retrying?

Comment: the client runs on an IoT device.  I have updated the question. @MatthijsvanderVeer

Comment: @Magnus  Yes, currently it is trying every configured minutes/seconds, but I want to retry exponentially when status is Disconnected_Retrying. basically want to give time to server to respond.